# How do I convert this line of HTML/Erb into HAML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I made the mistake of making an application with HAML, but am rolling with it now.

I'm trying to convert

```
<% if job.user == current_user %>
```

into HAML. Any suggestions? I can give more context if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write it like this:

```
- if job.user == current_user
```

The `-` says to evaluate the line as Ruby code, but suppress output into the document.